# how to add animated image like gif in smartface app studio

Tags: smartface.io

Trying to make my own progressing/loading message dialog by keeping an animated image like GIF in it. But, its not working.
Can any one help me how to use the animated images in Smartface app studio.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Up to now, only png files were being used to show icons in Smartface.

But, with the new release (4.5.0), "Assets" folder will be in use. You will be able to place different kind of files inside this folder, and you can reach them such as below :

```
assets://myfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks merve. With these assets, can i use animated images too?